# Simple time series linear regression

Tags: python, time-series, linear-regression

I have a date in year/m/d and a amount of sales in my data set. I am trying to use linear regression on my data but for some reason it isn't working, I have gone through tons of open questions about it but I am not finding what I need.

Here is my code:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

X = df[['Date']] 
y = df['Sales'] 

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X, y)

X_predict = [['2021-1-1']]
y_predict = model.predict(X_predict)
```

Comment: can you tell us what kind of error were occured?

Comment: ValueError: Unable to convert array of bytes/strings into decimal numbers with dtype='numeric' @Kang

Answer (score 0):

Since you get following error due to one of your columns most probably timestamp is suppose to be numeric before apply regression:

> ValueError: Unable to convert array of bytes/strings into decimal numbers with dtype='numeric'

I assume that it's better to index the timestamp within your dataframe to avoid this.Try the following:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

#Generate data for 20 days
x1 = np.arange(1, 21) + 0.3 * (np.random.random(size=(20,)) - 0.5)
x2 = np.arange(1, 21) + 0.2 * (np.random.random(size=(20,)) - 0.5)
start = dt.datetime.strptime("1 Nov 01", "%d %b %y")
daterange = pd.date_range(start, periods=20)
table = {"Sale": x1, "Date": daterange}
df = pd.DataFrame(table)
df.set_index("Date", inplace=True)
#df


#Data split
time_sample='2001-11-16'

time_stamp_index = df.index.get_loc(pd.Timestamp(time_sample),method='pad')


X_train = df.iloc[:time_stamp_index,:].values
y_train = df.iloc[:time_stamp_index,:].values
X_test = df.iloc[time_stamp_index:,:].values
y_test = df.iloc[time_stamp_index:,:].values

#Apply regression
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_predict = model.predict(X_test)

#plot the results
train_set = df.iloc[:time_stamp_index,:]
test_set = df.iloc[time_stamp_index:,:]
test_set_copy = test_set.copy()



import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use("fivethirtyeight")

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 10))

plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.ylabel("Values")
plt.title(f" Plot")

plt.plot(train_set,label='trainingSet')
plt.plot(test_set,"k",label='testSet')
plt.plot(test_set_copy,'r--',label='RF_predict')
plt.legend()
```

output:

[image: img]